# autonomous navigation

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create an autonomous robot, i start with installing ROS indigo on ubuntu, and i arrived to create a map manually with hector slam and teleop keyboard (i use arduino mega and motors with encoders).
Now i want to launch a file for autonomous navigation on unknown map, what can i do please?
i already saw hector navigation but i don't understand how it works

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240011/autonomous-navigation/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the Hector Navigation Stack there is also a hector_exploration_node and a hector_exploration controller. The hector_exploration controller will publish twist messages on the cmd_vel topic. These values will give you a velocity x and an angular z.

If you are using arduino, in the arduino code you need to subscribe to the cmd_vel topic, and then manipulate the values there.

If you want to test and see if you publish values on cmd_vel, run your laser scanner and hector slam and then run

*roslaunch hector_exploration node exploration_planner.launch*

and

*rosrun hector_exploration_controller simple_exploration_controller*

then you need to listen to the topic

*rostopic echo cmd_vel*

After that you should see a stream of values. Mine comes out in bursts.
Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) with karma: 64 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-07-21**:
i do this but i receive x=0 y=0 and z=1.4, and the motors don't stop,, it is not synchronised with hector slam.
what can i do in this case please?